# Adding subtotals to multiple tables on different tabs?

Tags: excel

I have about 50 tabs that I would like to add subtotals to. I need to keep these tabs as non-tables so that I can move them from one workbook to another. I have already created a macro to move them to the workbook I need them to be in and make only those tabs tables.

I would now like to create a macro to make those tabs have subtotals. They all have the same row lengths, but certain tabs have additional columns. Furthermore, some columns will be averages and some will be sums. Any advice or help on how I could approach this would be greatly appreciated! I don't have much experience with VBA and am finding it tough to start to take a crack on this part.

Thank you!

**

- Edit: The below code is an example of what I am trying to do using
  macro editor, but need to make it generic to go off of whatever table
  is in the specified range using a loop of tabs

**

```
Sheets("Net Sales").Select
Range("F11").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(Active).ShowTotals = True
Range("Table2[[#Totals],[Var %]]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns("Var %").TotalsCalculation = 
xlTotalsCalculationAverage
Range("Table2[[#Totals],[Var $]]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns("Var $").TotalsCalculation = 
xlTotalsCalculationSum
Range("Table2[[#Totals],[2018B $]]").Select
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.subtotal

Comment: It's tough to give advice without seeing examples of your data, but it sounds like a pretty scary workbook (or more of a database) . . . It might be time to consider [migrating the data storage to Access](https://support.office.com/article/move-data-from-excel-to-access-90c35a40-bcc3-46d9-aa7f-4106f78850b4).

Comment: Maybe this would help? This is an example of what is looks like through macro recorder, I just need to find a way to make this generic so that I can add a loop to it: